Metric currents on singular measures in $\mathbb R^d$
Unless I am misunderstanding a lot of works, it is my understanding that a finite and non negative measure $\mu=g\mathcal{H}^\alpha$, where $\mathcal{H}^\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-Haudorff measure, admits $\lfloor{\alpha}\rfloor$ Alberti representations.
This is the united effort of a papers by Bate, De Philippis, Schioppa and others.
In particular this should mean that any continuous curve $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ will be so that its graph has dimension $\alpha\geq 1$ and will always admit at least one Alberti representation.
What I fail to see is how the Lipschitz curves of this representation will be chosen as it feels like an unreasonable idea to be able to split the graph of the Weierstrass function as a superposition of Lipschitz fragments.
Am I misunderstanding something and this is impossible?
Or given any continuous map $g:t\mapsto (t,f(t))$ we can construct a bounded nowhere zero vector field $X:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ such that $X g_\#\mathcal{L}^1$ is a metric current?

I don't think $\mathcal H^\alpha|_E$ necessarily admits an Alberti rep. if $\mathcal H^\alpha(E)<\infty$ and $\alpha>1$, e.g. $E=$ Van Koch snowflake.

@Teri but that is literally my question. Do you have a proof that the Koch snowflake has no Alberti representation? It would be very helpful to see it.

It should follow from the fact that $E$ is purely 1-unrectifiable. If $\mathcal H^\alpha|_E$ had an alberti representation, you could find a non-trivial bi-Lipschitz piece of a curve (1-rectifiable set) inside $E$.

@Teri yes, that sounds very circular: a set is purely 1-unrectifiable if and only if it has no Alberti representation. Is there a proof that $E$ doesn't have fragments in it?

The equivalence you claim doesn't hold, I don't think (only one implication). I don't have a reference in mind for the pure unrectifiability of the Van Koch snowflake, but you could check e.g. Falconers Geometry of Fractal Sets or Mattila's Geometry of Sets and measures in Euclidean spaces.

@Teri The equivalence comes from a Theorem in Rudin "Function Theory in the Unit Ball of Cn" where if you take a compact convex set of measures you can write your measure as a a sum of something absolutely continuous to some measures in that set and something singular with respect to all. So by taking the measures given by integrals of lipschiz curves on [0,1] you get that the assumption of not having Alb rep is equivalent to your measure being singular to all Lipschitz curves thus unrectifiable. I tried parsing Mattila days ago, I'll see about Falconers. Thanks for the recommendation.

It can indeed happen that your measure is singular wrt $\mathcal H^1|_{\gamma}$ for all curve fragments $\gamma$, but this doesn't mean the space is purely 1-unrectifiable. For example, the Sierpinski gasket with the correct dimensional Hausdorff measure (and Euclidean metric) is quasiconvex, in particular contains full line segments (and thus isn't purely 1-unrectifiable). However the measure does not admit any Alberti representation.

@Teri thank you. This was the example I needed to see why a theorem in a 15 year old unpublished paper is wrong that was driving me mad. Falconer's book was also useful, thank you again for bringing it to my attention.

The implication does not work. What it is true is that if a measure admits $k$ Alberti representations, it is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathcal H^k$. Actually, it is absolutely continuous with respect to the $k$-integral geometric measure. In particular, if the measure is concentrated on a $\mathcal H^k$ $\sigma$-finte set and  admits $k$ Alberti representations, it is $k$-rectifiable.
A counterexample to your claim is $\mathcal H^1$ restricted to $E=K\times K$ where $K$ is the $1/4$ Cantor set. Indeed $E$ is purely unrectiable.

Yeah I have finally understood the 1/4 cantor set just this afternoon. What I don't understand is the two implications you have mentioned. If I take the measure on the standard 1/3 cantor set $\nu$ and consider $\nu\times \mathcal{L}^1$ restricted to $[0,1]^2$, won't this be a measure with only 1 Alberti representation but not absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mathcal{H}^1$? Moreover the 1/4 cantor set times itself is a $\sigma$ finite set for $\mathcal{H}^1$, wouldn't your claim make it 1-rectifiable?

In your first example the measure is indeed absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathcal H^1$, any  $\mathcal H^1$ negligible set, it is also $nu \times \mathcal L^1$ negligible. i probably do not understand the second question, the cartesian product of $1/4$ Cantor set with itself is is purely not rectifiable, and this is coherent with the fact that it has no Alberti representations.

Ah yes, i forget the importance of sigma finiteness for radon nykodym for my first example. The second question comes from your assertion "In particular, if the measure is concentrated on a $\mathcal{H}^k$ σ-finte set, it is k-rectifiable." I am missing something to make it coherent with the cantor set example.

I wil edit the answer to make it more clear "In particular if a measure is concentrated on a $k$-rectifiable set and it admits $k$ independent Alberti representations, it is $k$-rectifiable"
